# An effective enumeration of recursive sets in increasing order

Tags: computability, recursion

**Definition:** We call a set recursive if its characteristic function is recursive.

**Claim:** If the set $A\subset\mathbb N$ is recursive then $A=Range(f)$ for some recursive and increasing function.

**Proof:** If $A$ is infinite define $h$ by

$$h(0)=\mu z[\chi_A(z)=1]$$
$$h(x+1)=\mu z[\chi_A(z)=1\land z>h(x)]$$

Here $\mu,\chi_A$ are the minimization operator and $A$'s characteristic function respectively.

If $A$ is finite then $A=\{a_1,\dots a_n\}$ with $a_1<a_2\dots<a_n$. Now define $h$ by

$h(i)=\begin{cases}
a_i & i<n \\
a_n & i\geq n\\
\end{cases}$

Clearly in each case the function $h$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem.

**Questions:**

**1)** Unless we can effectively decide on the ordinality of sets, the above procedure is ineffective. What is an effective procedure for enumerating recursive sets in increasing order?

**2)** If the set $A$ is infinite can we choose a strictly monotone enumeration function that is primitive recursive?

Comment: I've just given you an answer to your previous question which also solves this one:

Comment: No, sir, you have not, as is apparent from my comment on you answer. (I am adding a link to [the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603212/all-infinite-recursive-sets-can-be-enumerated-by-an-injective-function).)

Comment: Do you want one enumeration of all sets (outputting one set after another in some appropriate representation), or just for each set an enumeration of that set?

Comment: I only wanted an enumeration for each set, but now that you've got my curiosity, I want both.

Comment: @Ivan: I cannot think of a reasonable representation of recursive sets that would allow them all to be enumerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), obviously not -- given an infinite decidable subset of $\mathbb N$, there is exactly one strictly monotone function that enumerates it, and that function does not have to be primitive recursive, as for example with
$$ \{n\mid \exists k<n: n=\mathsf A(k,k)\} $$
where $\mathsf A$ is Ackermann's function, which *by construction* is not primitive recursive.

For (1), it sounds like you want a procedure that takes an (always halting) *program* and a produces different program that enumerates its accept set in non-decreasing order. Once you accept repetitions (which is necessary to deal with finite sets), this should be as easy as creating a program that computes

$$ f(n) = \max\bigl( (A \cap \{ 0,1,\ldots,n \})\cup\{\min A\} \bigr)$$

... as long as $A$ is not empty, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so a couple of things.

Suppose that you know the index $e$ such that $\varphi_e$ is the indicator function for a nonempty recursive set $A$ (so we are promised that $\varphi_e$ is total recursive and not identically zero).  Then:
- If you don't mind repeating elements, take $f(e,n) = n$ if $\varphi_e(n) = 1$ and $f(e, n) = f(e, n-1)$ otherwise, while $f(e, 0) = \mu x(\varphi_e(x) =1)$.
- If you don't like repeating elements in your enumeration of infinite recursive sets, you are out of luck.  Determining whether $\varphi_e$ is eventually $0$ (i.e., $A$ is finite) is not a computable task, nor is determining whether it is identically zero.  You could solve the halting problem if you could solve this.

This function of course doesn't converge for most $n$ when $\varphi_e$ is not total recursive (or when $\phi_e$ is never $1$).  If you need $f(e,n)$ to be an increasing enumeration when $\varphi_e$ is total recursive and the indicator function for a nonempty recursive set, and *also* be a total recursive function, you are again out of luck.  Once again this would solve the halting problem.